# Error: invalid_request Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Uri must consist of printable ASCII characters:

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api-php-client

I Created Client Id and API Key in the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0), I given same url in google console and in my config file

This is my url:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A81%2Fmoviemuseui%2Fpublic%2Flogin%2FcheckLogin+&client_id=XXXXXXXX-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force

I am getting a error

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_request
>
> Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Uri must consist of
> printable ASCII characters:
> localhost:81/moviemuseui/public/login/checkLogin

How to solve this, I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your redirect uri must NOT contain space " "

Comment: geez copy and paste, didnt even notice

Answer (score 0):

Excluded US-ASCII Characters disallowed within the URI syntax:

```
   control     = <US-ASCII coded characters 00-1F and 7F hexadecimal>
   space       = <US-ASCII coded character 20 hexadecimal>
   delims      = "<" | ">" | "#" | "%" | <">
```

There are also some characters that may be allowed in URI syntax but can cause problems.

```
"{" | "}" | "|" | "\" | "^" | "[" | "]" | "`"
```

And the following characters are absolutely reserved for a query component and they are used for specific meaning in the protocol.

```
";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to url encode everything.  The first call to for authentication just displays a page to your users for them to approve your access.  It is a normal HTTP GET you can test it in any webbrowser.

The following works:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&response_type=code

This one adds your redirect uri, remember redirect uri should point to the page where you would like to handle authentication.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http:// localhost:81/moviemuseui/public/login/checkLogin/Filename.php&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&response_type=code

I have a tutorial that explains how the calls should be put together: [Google 3 legged oauth2 flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

Question: If you are using the Google-api-php-client why are you building this manually?

**Your error Redirect_URI:** must match the page where you would like to handle the authentication. For example:  http:// localhost/google-api-php-client-samples/oauth2.php 
It should be set in the developer console, and used in your script.

Comment: Can we use anyother url like any siteurl instead of localhost as redirect_uri here ?

Comment: Redirect uri must match the URI you want the authentication returned to. If you are hosting it on your website then it must be that url and it must be set to the same url in the Google Developers console.

Comment: Can you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316162/installed-application-redirect-uri-mismatch-when-site-is-online

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the `URI` does not contains any spaces. I too had the same problem and was resolved by deleting the spaces at the end.

Comment: What does this add that the other answers don't?