# Installed Application Redirect uri mismatch on live site which is working on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, google-authentication

I have developed an google analytics plugin , Getting URI mismatch error on authentication . It is **working well on localhost** , but when I installed it on a site, It displays this error.

My redirect uri that is created on browser address bar during authentication and

**showing error uri mismatch**

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=auto&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics.readonly&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapp.mysite.com%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3Danalytica-admin-settings%2F&client_id=id.apps.googleusercontent.com&include_granted_scopes=true&hl=en&from_login=1&as=6532dbe8b26fcb0f&authuser=3

and on **localhost something like this and it is working**

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=auto&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics.readonly&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhttp://localhost/test/%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3Danalytica-admin-settings%2F&client_id=id.apps.googleusercontent.com&include_granted_scopes=true&hl=en&from_login=1&as=6532dbe8b26fcb0f&authuser=3

*The only difference in bot the url is the redirect URI, one is one localhost and the other one is live .*

With " `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`" as redirect URI with a popup for authentication is working fine on both local site on live site. But the URL I have mentioned is working on localhost , but not working on live site.

on documentation [choosing a redirect uri for insatlledApp](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi)

**http://localhost[:port]

*This value signals to the Google Authorization Server that the authorization code should be returned as a query string parameter to the web server on the client. To receive the authorization code using this URL, **your application must be listening on the local web server.** This is possible on many, but not all, platforms. If your platform supports it, this is the recommended mechanism for obtaining the authorization code.*
**   Does it mean we can use it only on localhost ? but I have used a number of plugins which are using redirecturi for authorization .

Can anyone give me a solution for this or any idea, how I can achieve this.

This is how I am setting the redirect uri here.

```
$client->setRedirectUri( site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=analytica-admin-settings');
```

Installed app does not need redirect uri to be set on console. 
Check screenshot
[image]

Comment: did you add the second redirect uri in Google developers console?   What is the exact error you are getting it should display the redirect uri in the error message

Comment: It is an installed application as I have mentioned , It does not need to add redirect URL on console.

Comment: @DaImTo I have just added console screen.

Comment: That's a client id for native installed applications.  It doesn't have a redirect uri in it.  You need to create a client lid for web application.

Comment: yes, it does not have a redirect uri on console, but for authentication, I need to use choose between the three described here . I have chosen the first one, working well on localhost , but not working on live site.  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi

Comment: Try reading my blog post it might help http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-oauth2/

Comment: I have also gone thorough one of your blog post, you can notice, there is my comment regarding this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98203/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-daimto).

Comment: @DaImTo Can you come to chat ? that will be really helpful.